# How can I realize a staggered pricing model based on groups of four?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

hi i want to apply loop for on this equation `const adultPrice = privateAdultPrice + (adults -1) * privateAdultPrice2` and setting the limit on adults that after every 4 it repeats

```js
updateTotal();

function increaseCount(e, el) {
  var input = el.previousElementSibling;
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
  value++;
  input.value = value;
  updateTotal();
}

function decreaseCount(e, el) {
  var input = el.nextElementSibling;
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  if (value > 1) {
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    input.value = value;
    updateTotal();
  }
}

function decreaseCount2(e, el) {
  var input = el.nextElementSibling;
  var value = parseInt(input.value, 10);
  if (value > 0) {
    value = isNaN(value) ? 0 : value;
    value--;
    input.value = value;
    updateTotal();
  }
}


function calculateTotal() {
  const privateAdultPrice = 500;
  const privateAdultPrice2 = 125;



  const adults = +document.querySelector('#adults').value;


  const isPrivate = document.getElementById('private').checked;
 

  const adultPrice = privateAdultPrice + (adults -1) * privateAdultPrice2

  for (let i = adultPrice ; adults < 5; ++i)

  return i ;
}

function updateTotal() {
  const total = calculateTotal();
  console.log(total);
  document.querySelector('#amount').value = total;

  
}
updateTotal();
```

```html
<div class="total-price"><label class="total"> Total USD:</label><input type="number" id="amount"class="total" readonly></label> >
<div class="counter1">

  <div class='down' onclick='decreaseCount(event, this)'>-</div>
  <input id="adults" type='text' value='1' readonly>
  <div class='up' onclick='increaseCount(event, this)'>+</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%">
  <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="private"  autocomplete="off" checked="checked" onclick="updateTotal()">
  <label for="private">Private</label>
  
  <input type="radio" name="occupancy" id="shared" value="Shared Evening Safari" autocomplete="off" onclick="updateTotal()">
                    <label for="shared">Shared</label>
```

hi i want to apply loop for on this equation `const adultPrice = privateAdultPrice + (adults -1) * privateAdultPrice2` and setting the limit on adults that after every 4 it repeats

is it possible or i am in in illusion which is not possible at-all please help me on this one

```
for (let i = adultPrice ; adults < 5; ++i)
```

this is the problem i guess its not repeating

edited -------------------------------------------
formula should be applied depending on checkbox
let say a person select shared check box then price should change qty 1 = 125 and 125 x qty
if private selected then your formula should be applied

Comment: If you want to limit the number of tickets in the `increaseCount` function, you could use an `if` statement, for example `if (adults < 5) adults++`.

Comment: no i dont want to limit it like as you can see the  const adultPrice = privateAdultPrice + (adults -1) * privateAdultPrice2 which is like adultPrice = 500 +(qty -1) x 125 this thing works but till only 4th quantity i want this to repeat again after 4th quantity same way so lets say 5,9,13 qty and so on repeats the equation

Comment: Can you please explain to us what the intended results for 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9 adults would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this is more what you are looking for?

```js
const [ttl,adults,shared]=["amount","adults","shared"].map(id=>document.getElementById(id));
function calc(){ttl.value=(shared.checked?0:375)*Math.ceil(adults.value/4)+(adults.value*125);}
shared.onclick=calc;
document.querySelectorAll(".updown").forEach(el=>el.onclick=ev=>{
 adults.value=Math.max(1,+adults.value+(ev.target.textContent=="+"?1:-1));
 calc();
});
calc();
```

```html
<div class="total-price"><label class="total"> Total USD:</label><input type="number" id="amount" class="total" readonly></label>
<div class="counter1">
<div class="updown">-</div>
<input id="adults" type='text' value='1' readonly>
<div class="updown">+</div>
</div>
<div style="display: flex; width: 100%">
  <input type="checkbox" name="occupancy" id="shared">
  <label for="shared">shared evening safari (reduced price)</label>
```

As soon as a new group of 1 to 4 people is started, a base sum of $375 is added to the per-person charge of $125.

**UPDATE**

The `shared` checkbox now replaces the `private` one. If it is checked then the extra $375 starting each group for 4 will not e applied. If a smaller amount should still be applicable then that must be used in the formular instead of `0` : `(shared.checked?0:375)`.

Comment: wow thats what i wanted thanks man

Comment: if i wanted to learn this thing what should i be saying to google about this

Comment: like i might try to even put if condition based on the check box so was wondering what would be the scenario then let say if shared checkbox is been used then i want the total to be qty x 125 is that possible to do that with this coding style

Comment: and one more thing let say i would like to charge 150 so when i change 375 to 450 and 125 to 150 things go wrong

Comment: The applied method is basically logical thinking and a question of finding a linear formular. What do you mean by "shared checkbox", do you mean the one labeled "private"? And how exactly do you want it to affect the prices? Will the grouping still apply? If you want the second person to cause an increase of $150 and the price for 1 should still be $500 then you need to change the formula to `ttl.value=350*Math.ceil(adults.value/4)+(adults.value*150)`.

Comment: formula should be applied depending on checkbox let say a person select shared check box then price should change qty 1 = 125 and 125 x qty if private selected then your formula should be applied. sorry for going in detail